# system.nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object mvc asp.net view

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

[Hi Guys.My problem is that i won't  be able to display data that is coming from my controller to my view. i got this error.Someone can help me please !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY7nf.png)

```
    @model GRHModel.ListeDemandeConger
   @{
   ViewBag.Title = "AfficherMesDemandes";
   Layout = "~/Views/Home/Common.cshtml";
   }

   <table class="table table-responsive" style="width:400px">
   @foreach (var dc in  Model.ldc)
   {

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(i =>dc.DateDebut)
        </td>
    </tr>

   }

   </table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: where you are getting error?

Answer (score 0):

You model is null.
Surround your foreach with an IF checking if the model != null.

```
@if (Model != null)
{
   your foreach
}
```